# Sum of horizontal properties always equals width of the parent element? Is this true?

Tags: css

I am reading through Eric Meyer's *CSS: The Definitive Guide*, and in his chapter on the basics of the block-level box model, he makes the following statement:

> Remember that the total of the seven horizontal properties always equals the width of the parent element. As long as all properties are zero or greater, an element can never be wider than its parent’s content area.

By horizontal properties, he means these:

[image]

This strikes me as prima facie false. For example, what about a situation like this:

```
<div>
  <p>content</p>
</div>

div {
  width: 100px;
}

p {
  width: 300px;
}
```

The width of the containing block is 100 and the paragraph is 300, which means discounting all the other horizontal values the child paragraph will be unambiguously larger than its containing block's width (causing overflow). What am I missing?

Comment: Well, you are obviously finding a counter example. I don't know the book, maybe this assertion is true in the particular context of the example provided in the book.

Comment: The statement is made twice, fairly sweepingly, in two separate sections of the chapter on the basics of visual formatting, so I don't think it's specific to the examples in question. There may be something implied in the statement requires a knowledge of the finer nuances of CSS to catch. (e.g. I don't yet know enough to say whether computed vs current applies.) I first thought that the statement could be accounted for by containing blocks always expanding their width to accommodate any children, but a bit of experimentation show this not to be the case (overflow occurs). I remain puzzled. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you quote appears to mirror the following equation from [section 10.3 of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth):

> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other properties:
>
> > 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block

The spec, however, does continue as follows:

> If 'width' is not 'auto' and 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' (plus any of 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' that are not 'auto') is larger than the width of the containing block, then any 'auto' values for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' are, for the following rules, treated as zero.

This implies that the width of the block box *can* potentially violate this constraint without repercussion provided the specified value of the `width` property isn't `auto`. In particular, it does not say that the box needs to be resized in order to meet the constraint (other than auto margins being treated as zero, which is irrelevant in your case). Adjustments need only be made if the `width` property is `auto`, in which case the box is going to be dynamically sized anyway.

For some reason, section 10 does not directly specify how overflow should occur when the calculated width of a block box exceeds that of its containing block in such a way that the above constraint *cannot* be met. However, [section 11.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow-clipping), where [the `overflow` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) is introduced, very clearly states that overflow should occur in a situation precisely like the one you have demonstrated:

> Generally, the content of a block box is confined to the content edges of the box. In certain cases, a box may overflow, meaning its content lies partly or entirely outside of the box, e.g.:
>
> - ...
> - A block-level box is too wide for the containing block. This may happen when an element's 'width' property has a value that causes the generated block box to spill over sides of the containing block.

Note also the use of the word "Generally" here.

If related chapters of the book do not account for this exception, it may be an oversight. I can't say for sure, as I haven't read the book myself.

Comment: Hi, Does "`'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block`" implies width of content box of the containing block or the overall block box (including its own margins, padding, borders) of the containing block. Kindly clarify.

Comment: BTW, for normal block (static) elements, "containing block is formed by the content edge of the nearest block-level". This can be found at [safaribooks](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/css-pocket-reference/9780596515058/ch01s10s02.html) if you find the official docs a bit overwhelming or very bane.

Answer (score 2):

`Total of the seven horizontal properties always equals the width of the parent element.` - unless or until you decide to forcefully go against it,

**Example:**

- Defining width of child element larger then the parent.
- Usage of negative margins.

any one else know of other scenarios pls add in.

Comment: Hi, ur comment is very precise and to the point. BTW, why does negative margin expand the element beyond it's containing block edges rather than do a shifting the same distance (of negative margin vaue) from other end of the containing block. For e.g `margin-left: -30px;` will expand the overall width of `div` to `100% + 30px`. Why ?